# Listening for SMS and automatically replying to it in Android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

How to reply to an incoming message automatically in android?

Here's my onReceive() method from my IncomingSMS class which extends BroadcastRecevier, problem with it is that it sends many messages, I want it to send only one SMS reply.

```
public class IncomingSMS extends BroadcastReceiver{
private String senderNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    String message = "";            

    if(bundle != null){
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];



        for(int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
            senderNumber = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        }
        senderNumber = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sendMessage(senderNumber, "Thank you for sending me a message");
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String number, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Comment: are you sending to it to another number to test it?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to send just one SMS to that number (who originally sent a message), (it's part of a app, which will be installed on both the devices, sender and receiver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are facing is the normal behavior. Since you are listening for all incoming SMS, it is bound to send out a SMS again when it receives the thank you message. What you can do is, send a value or a boolean which is unique in the SMS and put a check for it. If the value exists you simply don't send the message again.

Comment: Yes you are right. My question is that how to implement such a functionality that the BroadcastReceiver on both devices don't keep on replying to each other. SmsManager class doesn't seem to have anything that can help, how would we send a boolean or a integer counter to check for repeat Sms?

Answer (score 0):

Onrecieve run after receiving of any part of sms and send a sms after of receiving of any part.i think you should set a time for receiving of part of sms and after pass that time you send reply of sms